# Set Data Via Collection Relation In Laravel Vue

Tags: php, laravel, object, vue.js, collections

I want To Set Data  Via Collection Relation In Laravel Vue. Here Is My Code

```
<div class="row row20">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="label">First Name</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.billing.firstName" placeholder="Frankie">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="label">Last Name</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.billing.lastName" placeholder="Apple">
</div>
```

The Code works fine if The User had Billing Data but gets error when the user has not set in billing information. When There is no billing information against a user it throws error 
`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"`

I dont know how to solve this, Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried doing console.log on user? user.billing doesnt exsist. maybe it wasn't loaded?

Comment: @hurnhu No Its Loaded But The User has not entered his Billing Information. `user.billing` returns null for that reason

Comment: on mount set user.billing to an object with lastName and firstName. user.billing = {lastName: '', firstName: ''}

Comment: you can use vform library to easily handle forms